# Is there a way to check the parameters and decide the routes based on the parameters in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am looking for a way to decide the routes based on a request parameter.For example i want to have route a request to web controller if it has params[:web] and to iPhone if it has params[:iphone]. Is it possible to do so keeping the names of the routes same but routing them to different controllers/actions depending upon the parameter?

Comment: It seems you're looking for something in the wrong place. If you want to render different views - take a look at user agent. There are quite some tutorials about distinguishing iphone and simple browser agents.

Comment: @eimantas with user-agent i can put a constraint on the whole route all i want is to have same named route but with different mapping (controller/action) depending upon the parameter.

Comment: You may want to read about "catch-all" controller. Also - don't bother with big big if statements, try case. And how about rather redirecting to a controller which is provided in a `param[:platform]`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible if you define route(or a named route) like below in your routes.rb file

```
map.connect '/:controller/:action/:platform',:controller => 'some controller name',:action=>'some action'
```

if you handle this in your action, you can use like params[:platform]

Read more on named routes if you customize more on this. As far as your prob is concerned I hope the above code solves the problem

Comment: an this code will point to the same controller but i want to decide the controller on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @lakshmanan's answer, you can do this:

Add this to your routes.rb:

```
map.named_route '/:controller/:action/:platform'
```

In your views,

```
<%= link_to "Blah blah", named_route_path(:controller => "some_controller",
                                          :action => "some_action",
                                          :platform => "some_platform")
```

In your some_controller,

```
def some_action
   if params[:platform] == "web"
        #DO SOMETHING
   elsif params[:platform] == "iphone"
        #DO SOMETHING
   else
        #DO SOMETHING
   end
end
```

Comment: There's a bug: you want == "iphone" instead of = "iphone".

Comment: That won't solve the purpose for me I want the named route to work with same name but different controller action mappings as there are certain extra checks and processing for certain parameters and i do not want to make my code cluttered with conditions in the same action and the response will also vary accordingly.

Comment: I am still not understanding what you exactly want. Probably if you could explain with pseudo-code, with an example case, it would be just great! Also i would agree with @Eimantas' comment, provided that you have tried it out, and you are sure that, that is not what you want! :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that there is a very good reason to have one controller accept this action (if there is shared code... move it to a helper method or model, and use the user agent info or named routes to your advantage), check the parameter and redirect to the appropriate controller and action:

```
def some_action 
   # some shared code here
   if params[:platform] == 'iphone'
     redirect_to :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'
   elsif params[:platform] == 'web'
     redirect_to :controller => 'baz', :action => 'baq'
   else
     # default controller and action here
   end
end
```

If you really really want the named route to map to different controllers, you'll need to hardcode the platform string:

```
map.connect '/foo/bars/:id/iphone', :controller => 'iphone',:action=>'some_action'
map.connect '/foo/bars/:id/web', :controller => 'web',:action=>'some_action'
```

*UPDATE0*

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399040/rails-routing-conditional-with-multiple-value-options), you might want to try `map.with_options(:conditions => ... )`